# Is there any gmail search operator that searches only those email messages having hyperlink in the email body?

Tags: gmail, gmail-api

I searched the operators [here](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7190?hl=en) but no luck. Any suggestions, please?

Comment: Your question is unclear you may want to read this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask then edit your question and try again.

Comment: I have edited my question description. Is it clear now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No** there are *no such operators* which can do that. Here is the [official link](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7190?hl=en) containing search operators.